# directorypress theme error mysql_error()

Tags: php, mysql

I installed directorypress theme to my wordpress site all works fine except this section " my purchase history" its sql error, but I can't deal with I want to remove this error or hide the link " my purchase history " form the parent page any idea?

the code in this part is

```
function MYORDERS($user_id){

global $wpdb,$PPT, $ThemeDesign, $userdata; get_currentuserinfo(); $content=""; $dwl_content=""; $td=1; $STRING ='<input type="hidden" value="" id="moreinfodiv" name="moreinfodiv">';
$date_format = get_option('date_format') . ' ' . get_option('time_format');
if(!is_numeric($user_id)){ die("nice try!"); }


$SQL = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."orderdata WHERE cus_id='".$userdata->ID."' GROUP BY order_id ORDER BY autoid DESC";  

$posts = mysql_query($SQL, $wpdb->dbh) or die(mysql_error().' on line: '.__LINE__);

  if ($posts && mysql_num_rows($posts) > 0) {

    while ($thepost = mysql_fetch_object($posts)) { if($thepost->order_total > 0){

    if($thepost->order_status ==0){  
    $status = $PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus0'));
    }elseif($thepost->order_status ==3){ 
    $status = "<b style='color:green;'>".$PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus1'))."</b>";
    }elseif($thepost->order_status ==5){ 
    $status = "<b style='color:green;'>".$PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus2'))."</b>";
    }elseif($thepost->order_status ==6){  
    $status = "<b style='color:red;'>".$PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus3'))."</b>";
    }elseif($thepost->order_status ==7){ 
    $status = "<b style='color:blue;'>".$PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus4'))."</b>";
    }elseif($thepost->order_status ==8){ 
    $status = "<b>".$PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus5'))."</b>";
    }
```

[image: error]

[image: the parent page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I got it
I changed the code to be

```
 $SQL = "SELECT * FROM 
   ".$wpdb->prefix."orderdata
   WHERE cus_id='".$userdata->ID."' 
   GROUP BY order_id 
   ORDER BY autoid DESC"; 
$results = $wpdb->get_results($SQL);
```

That solved the issue